# ZMQ REP socket not connecting the Dealer part of a proxy

Tags: ruby, zeromq

I have been playing around with ZMQ and love it. I am using it to build a distributed test execution application for use with Cucumber.  I am having a problem though. I am using a simple extended Req > Proxy > Reply pattern using the built int zmq_proxy.  I have everything set up and when I run it locally where all components are located on my machine, everything works perfectly.  But when I put the worker (the Rep socket) on another machine on the network, the Rep socket doesnt seem to ever make the connection to the Dealer socket that I passed into the zmq_proxy. I have tested a simple req > rep on the two machines and that works out just fine.  The problem seems to only be with the rep > proxy > rep pattern. The setup seems straight forward and will place the code below, but I just can't seem to get it to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is all done in Ruby 1.9.3 btw. Also, in the below setup the Client and the Proxy are on the same machine while the Worker is on a remote machine.

Client (Req socket)
    require 'ffi-rzmq'

```
context = ZMQ::Context.new
socket = context.socket(ZMQ::REQ)
socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5550')

socket.send_string "This is a message"

reply = ''

socket.recv_string reply

puts reply
```

Worker (Rep socket)

```
require 'ffi-rzmq'

context = ZMQ::Context.new
socket = context.socket(ZMQ::REP)
socket.connect 'tcp://ipAddressToDealer:5551'

message = ''

socket.recv_string message

puts message

socket.send_string "Got the messsage"
```

Proxy

```
require 'ffi-rzmq'

context = ZMQ::Context.new
front_end_socket = context.socket(ZMQ::ROUTER)
front_end_socket.bind('tcp://*:5550')

back_end_socket = context.socket(ZMQ::DEALER)
back_end_socket.bind('tcp://*:5551')

ZMQ::Device.new(front_end_socket, back_end_socket)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that windows firewall was blocking the Ruby Interpreter. I added exceptions in the firewall for the interpreter and everything is working as it should.  Not sure why it displayed the symptoms that it did though. I would imagine that the simple req > rep request would have been blocked as well.  Oh well, problem solved.